# Find a tag and hide another tag next to it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of TDs with two tags. I would like a way to find one of the tags and hide the other.

Here's what I have so far,

```
if($('td').find('.mark')) {
       $('.warning').hide();
    }
```

But I only want it to hide .warning in that particular TD and not all the .warning tags.

Here's the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/amQ4G/2/

Thank you

**UPDATE**

My apologies, I messed up on the HTML I'm working with, here's the HTML version I would it like it to work for, http://jsfiddle.net/amQ4G/9/

The tags being in separate TDs, one exists inside one TD, hide the other in the TD next to it.

Comment: I don't think your jsFiddle is a good example of what you want to do.

Comment: `.find()` does not return true/false. Check `.length` instead.

Comment: @SalmanA Thank you for the info, definitely will keep that in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be simply written as follows as well

```
$('tr').has('.mark').find('.warning').hide()
```

Updated according to question's update

Answer (score 2):

You could use the preceding sibling selector:

```
$('td .mark + .warning').hide()
```

Or more verbosely:

```
$('td').find('.mark').next('.warning').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution(for edited problem):

```
$('.mark'). //select all elements with the class 'mark'
parent(). //select the parent of all of those elements
parent(). //my grandpapy selector
find('.warning'). //find the children with the class 'warning'
hide(); //hide yo kids, hide yo wife, and hide yo husband cause they jQuerying everybody
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amQ4G/12/

Comment: This is hiding all the warning classes, I just want it to hide the one without the mark class

Answer (score 0):

Can u try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('td').find('.mark')) {
       $('.mark').parent('td').find('.warning').hide();
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/amQ4G/6/